# How to build react-treebeard project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, gruntjs

I am a browser based web programmer. For the last few years the simple and straight forward world of JavaScript development has been turned into a mayhem. For a tiny functionality one has to install a million things with correct versions through cryptic commands and esoteric error messages.

I wanted to use a simple widget at:
https://github.com/alexcurtis/react-treebeard

I have tried to build this project to use but now given up in deep frustration. If I had to list the number of things I have tried it will fill volumes. Can someone tell me how I can build this project on Windows 10?

Comment: This is too broad of a question for StackOverflow. Can you give examples of what you tried and what did not work? I do suggest looking at [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to start a new React project.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have node [installed](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

For using the widget you can install it through:

```
npm install --save react-treebeard
```

in a project. And bundle your project through a module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

---

Building the project from source is only required for contributing to the project. You should be able to do the following (inside a local clone):

1. Fetch all dependencies

   ```
   npm install
   ```
2. Build:

   ```
   npm run prepublish
   ```

Author has provided a demo, which can be viewed by using `npm run example`

Comment: I want to: 1.run example, 2. modify example, 3. repeat. But unable to run example as running above commands powershell is stuck at webpack compile with 5 warnings

Comment: OK. This is happening because the version of react specified in devDependencies is 0.14.x which is incompatible with the version of Radium being installed. You can update versions in devDependencies in package.json to: 
"react": "^15.0"
"react-dom": "^15.0"

Then the example will work fine.

Comment: You can file a bug with the project about this.

Comment: 16:25  warning  'style' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
  17:28  warning  'node' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  17:33  warning  'node.children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
  24:24  warning  'node' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
  24:29  warning  'node.name' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types

✖ 5 problems (0 errors, 5 warnings)

webpack: Compiled with warnings.

Comment: Those warnings are inconsequential. You can fix them at your convenience if you would like, but they should not prevent you from running the example.

Comment: and that is the unfortunate part, with npm run example, after these warnings powershell stops at that and opening the index.html in the browser displays error: If you can see this, something is broken (or JS is not enabled)!

Comment: pointing to http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/ also gives the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144163/discussion-between-sameer-singh-and-lorefnon).